# Is it haram to not say my religion to far people i know from internet and with whom i talked a long time?

Tags: halal-haram

Basically that, is it haram to avoid talking about religion with disbelievers whom i know from internet? Is it haram if i don't say to them that im a muslim and never say out loud arabic words, for them to not discover it and stuff like that?

Comment: No there issl no sin in it apparently

Comment: You can choose to whom you tell what as long as you don't lie